# join tables and for one table I want to get the newest result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I join some tables and in one table I only want to join the newest data limit 1.

For the table booking I want the newest data where car id exist

```
      SELECT

      car_details.mark,

      cars.name,
      cars.active,
      cars.status,

      station.id as station_id,
      station.location,

      booking.id as booking_id

      FROM car_details

      INNER JOIN cars
      ON car_details.car_id = cars.id

      INNER JOIN car_station
      ON car_station.car_id = cars.id

      INNER JOIN station
      ON station.id = car_station.station_id

      INNER JOIN booking
      ON booking.car_id = cars.id
      
      WHERE cars.id = $1

      LIMIT 1;
```

how can I do it ?

EDIT:

I want this data:

```
{
  rent_status: ... (Here I need the ID where car id = id and the newest booking id, because there are many bookings)
  active: ...,
  name: ...,
  station: ....
}
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @reacter777, how could we possibly know what data distinguishes the newest booking without at least a table description and possibly some sample data?  We are not mind readers here.  Help us out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the INNER JOIN to booking with a CROSS JOIN LATERAL subquery over booking.  The erstwhile join condition then goes inside the subquery

```
...
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM booking WHERE booking.car_id = cars.id ORDER BY something LIMIT 1) booking
...
```